# how will rails app create a db in server either from migration file or schema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails `app` which i ran so far in my local system and now i got to move it to the `server` so what i need to know is how will it create a `database` either using the migration files or the schema?

Also i would like to know if from migration, i added new fields and removed few migration file so how will it create the missing fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rails app is usually deployed to a server using a git repository. There are other ways to do it, but this is the way i prefer. Have a look at capistrano (https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano).

Its a set of tasks (also called receip) you can run from the console to deploy your app to your server. It can also run your migration on the server.

Basically, you have to create the database itself on your own. When the migrations are running on the server, they will create exactly the same database as they will create on your local machine. So if you deleted migrations they won't run (surprise, surprise!)